# How to update the location of /sdcard link to the external storage?

Tags: settings, external-sd, shell

I wonder how to do this.

Now, this is linked to my small internal memory.

I'm an experienced Linux user, but Android shell don't have `unlink` and `rm /sdcard` makes me fear.

What I try to do is to symlink `/storage/1234-5678` to `/sdcard`, but I see no way.

`ln -sfv /storage/1234-5678 /sdcard` is trying to create `/sdcard/1234-5678` unlike linux `ln`...

Don't know what I can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run

```
mount -o rw,remount /
ln -sfvn /storage/1234/5678 /sdcard
```

Option `-n` means "Don't dereference symlinks - treat it as a normal file". Even if you're running a linux you should use `ln -sfn`, though.